# FTP over SSH (SFTP) in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, sftp

I'm writing a simple Delphi app to upload a few files to a SFTP server. I thought I would be able to use a `TIdFTP` Indy client but it seams as tho their is not an option for FTP over SSH (SFTP). Does anyone know of any Free / Open source Components for Delphi 2010 that would support FTP over SSH (SFTP)? Due to security reasons I'm unable to use Active X controls, so please do not respond with Active X solutions.

Comment: [delphi wrapper for libssh2](https://bitbucket.org/ZeljkoMarjanovic/libssh2-delphi).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 11):

SFTP and "FTP over SSH" are two separate things, and neither involves SSL (as someone else has suggested).  SFTP is a sub-protocol of SSH while "FTP over SSH" is good/bad ol' FTP tunnelled through an SSH connection with port forwarding.

Either way, what you're after is a Delphi SSH library.  I was unable to find a free SSH library for Delphi and ended purchasing SecureBlackbox (http://www.eldos.com/), which is excellent by the way, although SecureBridge (http://www.devart.com) also looks pretty good.

Answer (score 9):

1) SFTP is NOT FTP-over-SSH. [Read the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440463/differences-between-sftp-and-ftp-over-ssh).

2) For SFTP there are no free Delphi components. You can use our [SFTP client and server components for Delphi](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/delphi-sftp.php) (part of SecureBlackbox product), which are supported and maintained commercial solution.

Comment: Hmm, looks interesting and legit.

Comment: This is being flagged as spam; AFAIK linking to *related* commercial solutions, especially by a well-established account, is not spam. If this was a new account with 1 rep, that would be a different story.

Comment: Also, the post is clear about his affiliation with the product; answers like this should be encouraged.

Comment: Edited because I think that the name Secure black Box makes it clearer . I have posted this name in answer to several questions on StackOverflow and I think it helps this answer to have the full commercial name of the product.

Comment: @WarrenP Thank you for correction yet the "right" name as accepted by US Patent Office is "SecureBlackbox" (as one word) because there exist some other software titles with "blackbox" in their names.

Comment: There's a free component now: 
https://github.com/superflexible/TGPuttyLib

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/)'s SCP command line utility, with catching it's standard out via the [CreateProcess method](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_2.htm).

Answer (score 4):

IP*Works include SFTP component - http://www.nsoftware.com/products/component/sftp.aspx and registered user of Delphi XE a XE2 can download this from code central (ID: 28437, ID: 28012)

and for Synapse is in contrib dir demo of simple SFTP - http://synapse.ararat.cz/files/contrib/

Comment: Sorry, this version of `IP*Works` does not include `IP*Works SSH`, so no SFTP support is found here.

Answer (score 3):

And since October 2019, there's a DLL fork of PuTTY with Delphi units, please see
https://github.com/superflexible/TGPuttyLib

This was created to be able to achieve the highest possible transfer rates over SFTP. It's free and very easy to use (with examples).

Answer (score 0):

Look at Synapse ( http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download ) suporting ssl protocole.
Exemple code: http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/public:howto:tcpwithssl

Comment: SFTP has nothing to do with SSL. Neither SSH does.

Comment: you are right, i had SSL in mind, but does an SSH connection to a server can be established using the SSL protocol?

Comment: Doing some research about synapse i came upon this: http://leonardorame.blogspot.com/2010/01/synapse-based-ssh-client.html

Comment: SSH and SSL are different (though similar in some aspects) technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Another secure connection component set is from nSoftware: http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssh/components.aspx

You get SSH Tunnel, and SFTP.

They also offer a full component set of SSL related items: http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssl/components.aspx

Answer (score 0):

libssh2 (wriiten in C) supports SFTP, and we have two **separate** Delphi wrappers (not sure which one is better):

https://github.com/pult/libssh2_delphi
and
https://github.com/dimmaq/delphi-libssh2

SecureBridge from DevArt also support SFTP, comes with full source for the Professional Editon.